# Run ToProperty before subscription

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have a `ReactiveCommand` that produces an integer as output.

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, int> Calculate { get; }
```

The latest result from this command is stored in a variable using `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> _latestValue;
public int LatestValue => _latestValue.Value;
...
Update.ToProperty(this, vm => vm.LatestValue, out _latestValue);
```

Every time `Calculate` is run, its output is stored in `LatestValue`.
However, I encounter a problem when I do something like this:

```
anotherObservable.SelectMany(_ => Calculate.Execute())
    .Select(value => value == LatestValue);
```

The result from this observable seems to always be false because Select() is run before `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` updates `LatestValue`, and so `LatestValue` has an outdated value.

This is a problem because I want to run a function when the observable produces a value, and this function needs the latest value from `Calculate`. I can't pass the new value from the observable, it needs to be in the variable.

I thought about doing something like executing `Calculate` and then waiting for an update of `LatestValue` using `WhenAnyValue`. However this is error-prone as the update may be caused by a previous execution and it generally seems like bad design.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the intent of storing the latest value? Is it to ensure that you get the latest value in case of multiple executions of `Calculate` in quick succession?

Comment: In reality, Calculate is a function that validates a viewmodel.  The function is quite costly and the validity of the viewmodel is checked in multiple places across the code. Some functions in the codebase are non-reactive and so cant use the observable, but need the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the best solution would be to use a `WhenAnyValue` on the `LatestValue` property. That way you’re certain to only have the most recent value at any moment.

As you mention, you get a race condition and I think it’s best avoided by not doing what’s basically the same work in to places at the same time. Let the OAPH get set and work from that.

You might want to skip the first signal of the `WhenAnyValue` (with `Skip(1)`) as the current value of the property is returned immediately.